# Почему при нажатии на popup он закрывается?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Открытие popup происходит хорошо, но когда я нажимаю на содержимое popup например на один из input то он сразу закрывается, как я это могу решить?

```js
const openButtonProduct = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-item__edit');
if(openButtonProduct) {
  const closeButtonProduct = document.querySelector('.cart-popup__close');
  const popupProduct = document.querySelector('.cart-popup');
  const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay')

  overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popupProduct.classList.add('hidden')
  })

  openButtonProduct.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      popupProduct.classList.remove('hidden')
    });
  
    closeButtonProduct.addEventListener('click', function() {
      popupProduct.classList.add('hidden')
    });
  });
}
```

```css
cart-popup {
    display: flex;

    &__wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 92;
    }

    &__left {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        gap: 10px;
    }

    &__body {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        gap: 20px;
        padding: 40px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        box-shadow: 0px 14px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

    &__close {
        position: absolute;
        top: -60px;
        right: 0;
    }

    &__img {
        width: 240px;
        height: 268px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #E4E4E5;
        border-radius: 22px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    &__price-now {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    
    &__heading {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 18px;
        gap: 3px;

        h4 {
            margin-bottom: 4px;
        }
    }

    &__textarea {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px;
        background: #E8E8E8;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #6A6A6A;
        line-height: 15px;
        height: 65px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    &__input {
        width: 300px;
    }

    &__buttons {
        display: flex;
        gap: 10px;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    &__cancel {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #6A6A6A;
        background: #E8E8E8;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    &__save {
        padding: 15px 27px;
    }

    &__col {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 15px;
    }

    &__col--left {
        gap: 30px;
    }

    &__help {
        margin-top: 4px;
        font-size: 10px;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-decoration-color: #c30101;
    }

    &__form {
        display: flex;
        gap: 40px;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }
} 


.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  z-index: 88;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-popup hidden">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="cart-popup__wrapper">
            <div class="cart-popup__body">
                <div class="cart-popup__left">
                    <button class="cart-popup__edit"><img src="/images/cart/edit.svg" alt=""></button>
                    <div class="cart-popup__image">
                        <div class="cart-popup__product">
                            <div class="cart-popup__img">
                                <img src="/images/cart/vtb.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">
                                <div class="price__now cart-popup__price-now">
                                    <p>от 417.00 BYN</p> 
                                    <div class="product__question--red" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                      <img src="/images/icons/red-qustion.svg" alt="question">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="price__sale">
                                  <p class="price__cost">от 507.00 BYN</p>
                                  <p class="price__percent">-18%</p>
                                  <div class="product__time" data-qustion="До конца акции 5 дней, 5 часов и 5 минут!">
                                    <img src="/images/cart/sale.svg" alt="sale">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>
                
                <div class="cart-popup__right">
                    <a class="title" href="/product.html">НАЗВАНИЕ ПРОДУКТА<img src="/images/icons/link-icon.svg" alt=""></a>
                    <form action="" class="cart-popup__form">
                        <div class="cart-popup__col">
                            <div class="cart-popup__group">
                                <div class="product__title">
                                    <p>Ваши пожелания</p> 
                                    <div class="product__question" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                      <img src="/images/product/question.svg" alt="question">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                <textarea name="" id="" class="cart-popup__textarea">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
                                </textarea>
                                <div class="cart-popup__help red-text"><a href="/text-example.html">Нету текста для награды?</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-popup__group">
                                <div class="product__title">
                                    <p>Ориентировочные размеры</p> 
                                    <div class="product__question" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                      <img src="/images/product/question.svg" alt="question">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                <input type="text" class="input-text cart-popup__input" value="300*500*100 мм">
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-popup__group">
                                <div class="product__title">
                                    <p>Дополнительные опции</p> 
                                    <div class="product__question" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                      <img src="/images/product/question.svg" alt="question">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                <select class="select">
                                    <option selected>Выберите</option>
                                    <option>Cappuccino</option>
                                    <option>Espresso</option>
                                    <option>Latte</option>
                                    <option>Mocha</option>
                                    <option>Frappe</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-popup__buttons">
                                <button class="cart-popup__save red-btn">Сохранить</button>
                                <button class="cart-popup__cancel">Отмена</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-popup__col cart-popup__col--left">
                            <div class="cart-popup__group">
                                <div class="product__title">
                                    <p>Крайний срок готовности</p> 
                                    <div class="product__question" data-qustion="Краткая подсказка: например, по цене: ещё раз повторить, что она не окончательная">
                                      <img src="/images/product/question.svg" alt="question">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                <input type="date">
                            </div>
                            <div class="cart-popup__group">
                                <div class="cart-popup__heading">
                                    <h4>Количествои</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="counter">
                                    <div class="counter__wrapper">
                                        <button class="counter__btn--plus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/minus.svg" alt="minus"></button>
                                        <input type="number" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1" class="counter__input">
                                        <button class="counter__btn--minus" onclick="stepper(this)"><img src="/images/cart/plus.svg" alt="plus"></button>
                                      </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <button class="cart-popup__close"><img src="/images/cart/close.svg" alt="close"></button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="question-tooltip">

            </div>
            <div class="tooltip--time"></div>
            <div class="question-tooltip--red"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас весь попап внутри оверлея, куда ни кликай, попадешь в него, оверлей ВСЕГДА должен быть вне элементов

Answer (score 1):

Потому что EventListener передаёться всем наследникам. Если например ты поставишь EventListener клика на BODY то куда-бы ты не кликнул он всегда отработает.

Решение? Проверить event.target. А точно-ли ты кликнул на свой элемент?!

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay')
overlay.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('overlay')) {
    popupProduct.classList.add('hidden')
  }
})
```

ps:

Кстати расскажу по секрету, на этом эффекте был основан `live` эффект в jQuery. Когда можно было привязать EventListener к несуществующему элементу.

```
$('a').live("click", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

Он по сути привязывал клик к body и уже после клика проверял target на совпадение с элементом.